# Learning PHP security and framework concepts

Tags: php

I am a Computer Science student. I know there is a saying "don't reinvent the wheel" however I feel that the best way to truly learn things is to write things from scratch. However then when the idea is understood, start using well established tools in the industry.

So far my PHP web applications are relative simple from PHP view point so I am trying to learn new frontiers such as security and framework concepts. I read [this](http://books.google.com/ebooks?id=HuDy3EYTK1YC) PHP security book for beginners. What would be other suggestions on going about learning more advanced security approaches in the industry? Also what would be the recommendations on learning more advanced PHP features and how to properly implement them such as URL rewrites (the processing of the rewrite since Apache takes care of the actual rewrites), and whatever else topics are a must learn for a PHP developer (or web developer - PHP, Python, Ruby, etc)?

Comment: I know this isn't really what you are asking for, but if I could give you just 1 tip is that you should log absolutely everything, especially errors. I know this is kind of a backwards approach, fixing things in stead of preventing them. But it is a proven method (look at planes and their black (orange) boxes!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essential PHP Security is indeed an excellent resource. I would also recommend [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) as well as [Pro PHP Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595084). If you take the approach that *everything* is suspect, you will code more securely.

As for mod_rewrite, there are plenty of tutorials on the net and for best coding practices check out some of the tutorials and articles on Smashing Magazine.

Comment: The OWASP site would've been one of my sugestions if you wouldn't placed it... :)

Answer (score 2):

You should consult (besides the books) some of the blogs and online resources, like the [Chris Shiflett's Blog](http://shiflett.org), which is an outstanding resource and home of most of the more important articles on security.

Another important advice I took from a book I've read

> **Inmature artist imitate, mature
>   artists steal**

If you want to do some good stuff, go ahead and disect the common and known CMS in PHP, like [Joomla](http://joomla.org)(Personal Favourite), Kohana, Wordpress and CodeIgniter. Disecting those systems and snooping around to see their entrails is the best way to learn.

Hope I can help!

Comment: I once thought dissecting other frameworks would be the best approach, until I realize such things were just trying to sell me an idea of what I needed. Ended up adopting `DDD` (Domain-Driven Design) as a coding practice, thus allowing me to shape scripting like an artist instead of using a scripting language as if it were compiled (PHP is what is is in the end).